# distutilscross issue when install PyAudio for cross-platform

Tags: python

When I installed PyAuduo for my MIPS embedded platform, I got this error:

```
 running build
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "setup.py", line 122, in <module>
 extra_link_args=extra_link_args)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
     dist.run_commands()
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/distutils/dist.py", line 955, in 
   run_commands
   self.run_command(cmd)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/distutils/dist.py", line 973, in 
 run_command
   cmd_obj.ensure_finalized()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/distutils/cmd.py", line 107, in  
     ensure_finalized
   self.finalize_options()
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/distutilscross-0.1-   
    py3.5.egg/distutilscross/crosscompile.py", line 16, in finalize_options
   AttributeError: '_Environ' object has no attribute 'has_key'
```

It seems "crosscompile.py" cannot run python3 normally. 
Does anyone have idea how to modify the code in crosscompile.py to work normally in pyhton3?

Comment: the code is [def finalize_options(self):
        if self.cross_compile and os.environ.has_key('PYTHONXCPREFIX'):
            prefix = os.environ['PYTHONXCPREFIX']
            sysconfig.get_python_lib = get_python_lib
            sysconfig.PREFIX = prefix
            sysconfig.EXEC_PREFIX = prefix
            # reinitialize variables
            sysconfig._config_vars = None
            sysconfig.get_config_var("LDSHARED")

        _build.finalize_options(self)]
could you provide the example about how to modify for python3.5?

Answer (score 0):

[how to solve AttributeError: '_Environ' object has no attribute 'has_key'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8427352/how-to-solve-attributeerror-environ-object-has-no-attribute-has-key)

It seems like PyAudio was built in Python 2x. Python 2x had support for `has_key()` function to check if keys existed in dictionaries. In Python 3x, you simply do this:

```
if 'the_key' in os.environ:
```

You can potentially change this line in `crosscompile.py` as a quickfix and then contact the developer (`http://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/#contact`).

Comment: the code is :
`def finalize_options(self):
        if self.cross_compile and os.environ.has_key('PYTHONXCPREFIX'):
            prefix = os.environ['PYTHONXCPREFIX']
            sysconfig.get_python_lib = get_python_lib
            sysconfig.PREFIX = prefix
            sysconfig.EXEC_PREFIX = prefix
            # reinitialize variables
            sysconfig._config_vars = None
            sysconfig.get_config_var("LDSHARED")

        _build.finalize_options(self)`
could you show the example about how to modify to work for python3.5?