# python2 code get error when using python3.5

Tags: python

```
def finalize_options(self):
    if self.cross_compile and os.environ.has_key('PYTHONXCPREFIX'):
        prefix = os.environ['PYTHONXCPREFIX']
        sysconfig.get_python_lib = get_python_lib
        sysconfig.PREFIX = prefix
        sysconfig.EXEC_PREFIX = prefix
        # reinitialize variables
        sysconfig._config_vars = None
        sysconfig.get_config_var("LDSHARED")

    _build.finalize_options(self)
```

the code above that will get the error when run on python3.5.
the error is :
crosscompile.py", line 16, in finalize_options
AttributeError: '_Environ' object has no attribute 'has_key'

does anyone have idea how to modify the code to workable in python3.5?

Comment: Please see below: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40305172/distutilscross-issue-when-install-pyaudio-for-cross-platform/40305503#40305503

Comment: `'PYTHONXCPREFIX' in os.environ` in line #2?

Answer (score 4):

`has_key` is removed in python3, but you shouldn't be using it in 2 either. Use the `in` operator:

```
if self.cross_compile and 'PYTHONXCPREFIX' in os.environ:
```

Comment: what is the meaning of os.environ?
is about environment var PYTHONXCPREFIX?

Comment: @user1450650 os.environ is a dict containing all env vars from your system.

Answer (score 1):

[has_key() was removed in Python 3.x.](https://docs.python.org/3.1/whatsnew/3.0.html#builtins)
 Use `in` or `get`

```
'PYTHONXCPREFIX' in os.environ
```

Using `get`

`os.environ.get('PYTHONXCPREFIX')`. if does not exists it returns None.

It can returns False as well, passing it as default value.

```
os.environ.get('PYTHONXCPREFIX', False)
```